# C - Verify win condition in Connect Four game

Tags: c, verify

This is the verification from a connect four game prototype, but it seems I've done something wrong.
I want that everytime the player is making a move, the function will verify if there he won or not, by verifying vertically, horizontally, and eventually, on the diagonal.
But it seems that it does not verify correctly, because in some cases, even though there are only 2 moves made, the functions returns 1.

```
    int verifyGame(int gamePosition, int gameVariable, char gameArray[HEIGTH][WIDTH])
{

  if(gameArray[gamePosition][gameVariable] == gameArray[gamePosition + 1][gameVariable] == gameArray[gamePosition + 2][gameVariable] == gameArray[gamePosition + 3][gameVariable]) //verify vertically
        return 1;
      else
        if(gameArray[gamePosition][gameVariable] == gameArray[gamePosition][gameVariable - 3] == gameArray[gamePosition][gameVariable - 2] == gameArray[gamePosition][gameVariable - 1]) //verify horizontally
          return 1;
      else
         if(gameArray[gamePosition][gameVariable] == gameArray[gamePosition][gameVariable - 2] == gameArray[gamePosition][gameVariable - 1] == gameArray[gamePosition][gameVariable + 1])
          return 1;
      else
         if(gameArray[gamePosition][gameVariable] == gameArray[gamePosition][gameVariable - 1] == gameArray[gamePosition][gameVariable + 1] == gameArray[gamePosition][gameVariable + 2])
          return 1;
      else
         if(gameArray[gamePosition][gameVariable] == gameArray[gamePosition][gameVariable + 1] == gameArray[gamePosition][gameVariable+ 2] == gameArray[gamePosition][gameVariable + 3])
          return 1;
      //verify diagonally


      else return 0;
};
```

This is where the function is called. The switch verifies the users input, and then it places the value in the matrix, and then verifies for won

```
    printf("playerPick is : %d\n", playerPick);
  fflush(stdout);
  switch(playerPick)
  {
    case 1:
     if(gameVariables[0] >0 && gameVariables[0] < 7)
      {
        --gameVariables[0];
        gameArray[gameVariables[0]][0] = (char) 82;
       ifWon = verifyGame(gameVariables[0], 0, gameArray);
      }
      printArray(gameArray);
      break;
    case 2:

      if(gameVariables[1] >0 && gameVariables[1] < 7)
      {
        --gameVariables[1];
        gameArray[gameVariables[1]][1] = (char) 82;
        ifWon = verifyGame(gameVariables[1], 1, gameArray);
      }
      printArray(gameArray);
      break;
    case 3:
      if(gameVariables[2] >0 && gameVariables[2] < 7)
        {
          --gameVariables[2];
          gameArray[gameVariables[2]][2] = (char) 82;
          ifWon = verifyGame(gameVariables[2], 2, gameArray);
        }
      printArray(gameArray);
      break;
    case 4:
      if(gameVariables[3] >0 && gameVariables[3] < 7)
        {
          --gameVariables[3];
          gameArray[gameVariables[3]][3] = (char) 82;
          ifWon = verifyGame(gameVariables[3], 3, gameArray);
        }
      printArray(gameArray);
      break;
    case 5:
      if(gameVariables[4] >0 && gameVariables[4] < 7)
      {
        --gameVariables[4];
        gameArray[gameVariables[4]][4] = (char) 82;
        ifWon = verifyGame(gameVariables[4], 4, gameArray);
      }
      printArray(gameArray);
      break;
    case 6:
      if(gameVariables[5] >0 && gameVariables[5] < 7)
      {
        --gameVariables[5];
        gameArray[gameVariables[5]][5] = (char) 82;
        ifWon = verifyGame(gameVariables[5], 5, gameArray);
      }
      printArray(gameArray);
      break;
    case 7:
      if(gameVariables[6] >0 && gameVariables[6] < 7)
      {
        --gameVariables[6];
        gameArray[gameVariables[6]][6] = (char) 82;
        ifWon = verifyGame(gameVariables[6], 6, gameArray);
      }
      printArray(gameArray);
      break;

  }
  printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", gameVariables[0], gameVariables[1], gameVariables[2], gameVariables[3], gameVariables[4], gameVariables[5], gameVariables[6]);
  printf("ifwon :  %d\n", ifWon);
```

Comment: The line: `gameArray[gameVariables[0]][0] = (char) 82;` could also be written as gameArray[gameVariables[0]][0] = \`R\`;

Comment: As a point of style, the code would be cleaner without all these `else`s because each `if` code block is ended by a `return`.

Comment: Ok. Still, is the verification any good? This is the worst part of the program, and if could really make it work, that would be great.

Comment: Instead of having all these cases, could you just pass the variable `playerPick` as the argument. i.e.  _gameVariables[playerPick]_, then use the derivative for the related expressions?

Comment: Hey, thanks, you were right, ryyker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot chain equality testing as you are attempting. The code will execute, but not as you suppose. Your code

```
if(gameArray[gamePosition][gameVariable] == 
   gameArray[gamePosition + 1][gameVariable] == 
   gameArray[gamePosition + 2][gameVariable] == 
   gameArray[gamePosition + 3][gameVariable])
```

must be split up into individual tests, such as:

```
if(gameArray[gamePosition][gameVariable] == gameArray[gamePosition + 1][gameVariable] &&
   gameArray[gamePosition][gameVariable] == gameArray[gamePosition + 2][gameVariable] &&
   gameArray[gamePosition][gameVariable] == gameArray[gamePosition + 3][gameVariable])
```

and on the other lines too.

Comment: That was what I was suspecting. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

@Weather Vane's answer is correct.  The logic used in your original post is not correct for a verification.

***One reason*** you may not have caught it yourself may be the complicated way it was written. Try simplifying the user input verification code: (Range checking the user input values is all that is necessary.)

```
//User input range checking:
if((gamePosition >= x)&&    //where `x` is minimum for gamePosition
   (gamePosition <= y)&&    //where `y` is maximum for gamePosition
   (gameVariable >= z)&&    //where `z` is minimum for gameVariable
   (gameVariable <= w))     //where `w` is maximum for gameVariable
{//continue }
else 
{
    printf("Invalid value.  Please re-enter");
    return -1;
}
```

***Another opportunity*** for simplification is to note that each of your case statements contain identical code, with the exception of the value of the case.  Because of this the entire `switch(...){...}` can be replaced with a single ***if*** statement:

```
//assuming playerPick >= 1
  if(gameVariables[playerPick-1] >0 && gameVariables[playerPick-1] < 7)
  {
    --gameVariables[playerPick-1];
    gameArray[gameVariables[playerPick-1]][playerPick-1] = (char) 82;
    ifWon = verifyGame(gameVariables[playerPick-1], playerPick-1, gameArray);
  }
  printArray(gameArray);
```

***Also note*** that although the statement:

```
gameArray[gameVariables[0][0] = (char) 82; //what is 82?
```

is perfectly legal, the variable gameArray[0][0] is just a char, so casting the value 82 is not necessary.  Also, C syntax provides a way to pull out the ***[ASCII](https://www.google.com/search?q=ascii+table&biw=1523&bih=733&tbm=isch&imgil=2U31hF4tTw886M%253A%253BJMtOixefP_tDJM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.asciitable.com%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=2U31hF4tTw886M%253A%252CJMtOixefP_tDJM%252C_&usg=__v-tVMaZvqb9Q_RD93Q9sEftM8Zg%3D&ved=0ahUKEwiFvbSmmfXJAhVM6GMKHeIUD2sQyjcILQ&ei=9kJ8VoXqO8zQjwPiqbzYBg#imgrc=2U31hF4tTw886M%3A&usg=__v-tVMaZvqb9Q_RD93Q9sEftM8Zg%3D)*** decimal value of the character by surrounding it with the graves symbol, allowing the following form, which is more readable:

```
gameArray[gameVariables[0]][0] = `R`;       //intuitive
```

Comment: Thanks, I've actually made all the modifications, and I'm going for the `if` statements now, hopefully it will work better.

Comment: @Justplayit94 - Note: 
The switch can be replaced with a _single if_ statement :)

Comment: It does indeed work, all I have to do now is make the diagonal verification and it's going to be great